# printing specific rows or columns in 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How do I print specific rows or columns in 2D array ex. I want to print the row in column 2
it should "IJKL" or print the column in row 3 and it should "DHLP"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[][] word = {{"A", "B", "C", "D", },
                            {"E", "F", "G", "H", },
                            {"I", "J", "K", "L", },
                            {"M", "N", "O", "P", }};

        for (int row = 0; row < word.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < word[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(word [row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MyMainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[][] word = { { "A", "B", "C", "D", }, { "E", "F", "G", "H", }, { "I", "J", "K", "L", },
            { "M", "N", "O", "P", } };

    for (int row = 0; row < word.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < word[row].length; col++) {
            //To Print Second Row
            if(row==2) {
                System.out.print(word[row][col] + " ");
            }
            //To Print Third Column
            if(col==3) {
                System.out.print(word[row][col] + " ");
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

You jus need to specify only those row/column in the if condition which you want to display...